# An exception that cannot be caught?

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, exception

I have the following code in my files:

In Class Customer.Page:

```
Try
    If Not SiteContent.CurrentUser(False) Is Nothing Then
        If Not SiteContent.CurrentUser(False).IsAdministrator OrElse SiteVariables.CustomerMode Then
            SiteContent.PageViewManager.Create(New List(Of Control))
        End If
    Else
        SiteContent.PageViewManager.Create(New List(Of Control))
    End If
Catch ex As Heritage.Web.Content.Items.Exceptions.ExceptionGroup
     My.Response.Write(ex.Message & "<br />" & ex.StackTrace & "<br />")
End Try
```

In Class Item

```
Public Overridable Sub CheckValidity()

    'If the item is recycled then return true'

    If IsRecycled() Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'ExceptionGroup to store all exceptions which are thrown due to invalid data.'

    Dim ExceptionGroup As New Exceptions.ExceptionGroup
    Try

        'Checks if the item already exists'

        Exists()
    Catch ex As Exception
        'Add any exception as a result of this function to the ExceptionGroup'

        ExceptionGroup.AddException(ex)
    End Try

    'Check each attribute - add any exception which occurs as a result of validating their values to the ExceptionGroup'

    For Each Attribute As Items.Attribute In GetAttributes
        If TypeOf Attribute Is StringAttribute Then
            Dim StringAttribute As StringAttribute = Attribute
            Try
                If Not StringAttribute.Validate(StringAttribute.Value) Then Throw New Exceptions.ItemExceptions.RequiredFieldException(StringAttribute.Name)
            Catch ex As Exception
                ExceptionGroup.AddException(ex)
            End Try
        ElseIf TypeOf Attribute Is IntegerAttribute Then
            Dim IntegerAttribute As IntegerAttribute = Attribute
            Try
                If Not IntegerAttribute.Validate(IntegerAttribute.Value) Then Throw New Exceptions.ItemExceptions.RequiredFieldException(IntegerAttribute.Name)
            Catch ex As Exception
                ExceptionGroup.AddException(ex)
            End Try
        ElseIf TypeOf Attribute Is DateTimeAttribute Then
            Dim DateTimeAttribute As DateTimeAttribute = Attribute
            Try
                If Not DateTimeAttribute.Validate(DateTimeAttribute.Value) Then Throw New Exceptions.ItemExceptions.InvalidFormatException(DateTimeAttribute.Name)
            Catch ex As Exception
                ExceptionGroup.AddException(ex)
            End Try
        End If
    Next

    'Rollback the transaction if the ExceptionGroup contains any Exceptions'

    If ExceptionGroup.Exceptions.Count > 0 Then
        RollbackTransaction()
        Throw ExceptionGroup
    End If
End Sub
```

I know this may all seem complicated, but you should be able to deduce that the first chunk of code catches the ExceptionGroup thrown in the second chunk of code.

This is basically part of a system where objects are created from rows in the database as and when one of the objects is first needed (i.e. many objects, of a specific type, is created for each row and then data is extracted for each one **only** when it is first requested. Each object stores an instance of DataRow from which the attributes within the object extract the piece of data they need when the value of the attribute is first requested).

My point is that it is a system I have made from scratch with no third party code and not using Linq or any other fancy stuff like that (nor do I want to, before anyone says to switch to Linq or anything like that).

Anyway the ExceptionGroup, as you can tell, is populated by other exceptions which are thrown by validation of each attribute.

Now heres the problem. On running the first chunk of code **without** the try catch statement, it throws a horrible red and yellow error screen. However **with** the try catch statement, it loads perfectly.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this weird behaviour? Has anyone ever encountered this behaviour before?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Richard

Comment: By the way I have tried looping through all the exceptions contained in the ExceptionGroup and outputting the message / stacktrace from those too. I have also tried adding controls to a panel in the masterpage too, to no avail.

Comment: What exceptions are in the group?

Comment: Thats what I cant find out. Based on the code in the validation function (which, now, is like 5 months old and I havent touched it since), it should be either Exceptions.ItemExceptions.RequiredFieldException or Exceptions.ItemExceptions.InvalidFormatException. It could also be System.Exception. But I have tried simply outputting "Hello World" if an ExceptionGroup is caught (in case Message and StackTrace are empty) and it still says nothing. Yet remove the try catch and an exception of type ExceptionGroup is thrown but not caught...

Comment: Ive just tried catching System.Exception, then outputting "Hello World" through Response.Write. I searched the source code for "Hello" and came up with nothing... I just have no idea what could possibly be causing this. I have made too many changes in the past day to undo them all.

Comment: One thing just occurred to me - the try catch statement is in the page_preinit method. I am not sure if you can output to the page in the preinit, can you? If not then that is probably the problem. I have tried throwing an exception in the try catch and found it is throwing the new exception successfully. I wouldve thought that trying to output in the preinit method would have thrown an exception, however. I will try some stuff out and get back here whether or not it is successful

Comment: ok shortened and the code has been sorted out - I couldnt find out how to comment code but ive put it in single quotes. And my last comment the answer is no - it doesnt work yet. I have tried adding the exceptions temporarily to a variable in Customer.Page, then adding it to the masterpage in the page_load event, but this doesnt work either.

Comment: Well it seems I can interact with the masterpage before and after the try / catch, so yes it is possible to interact with it in the page_preinit. However within the catch I cannot seem to interact with it in any way, almost as if an exception is not being thrown...

Comment: Well after lots of time reviewing the changes I made over the last day, and making loads more, I managed to stop the error occuring in the first place (just one line of code would have done lol)... Still dont understand why it wouldnt output the errors from the exceptions though - I tried the same code on the admin frontend, in the page_preinit, and it worked fine first time... its a mystery

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if the problem is with `Response.Write` and when you're trying to do it.  I've always considered `Response.Write` kinda a bad idea in ASP.net anyway, since there are much better ways to do things (that give you much more control over where and how the output appears, and aren't as likely to break if you're using MS's AJAX stuff, especially UpdatePanels).

Comment: Generally, I don't like controlling program flow with exceptions like this. Errors in ExceptionGroup are already handled, and just need to be documented. Rather than Throw ExceptionsGroup, I would try Return ExceptionsGroup from CheckValidity. Then you can use your Try/Catch for handling errors that haven't already been handled.

Comment: @cHao I know Response.Write is a bad idea - but it guarantees that the output is gonna be in one place, without any of my other code being able to affect it or the element which contains it. I only **ever** use it as a temporary measure anyway.

Comment: @Bill That is one way to do it. I suppose I could check if CheckValidity().Exceptions.Count > 0. The idea is that this is run when an administrator tries to add or update an item (for example a product). I use several try catches between there and the top level. All except the one in the masterpage catch System.Exception and rethrow if it is an ExceptionGroup, otherwise they log the exception and dispose of it. When the ExceptionGroup reaches the top level, the master page will output the errors in a readable format so the user can see "The Name you specified is already in use.". Continued...

Comment: @Bill (Continued): This is the only way I could figure out to send some errors to the top level and log some without telling the user. If you can think of a better way then please say so. At the moment it does seem to be pretty efficient - even the version which is live, which I have drastically improved since.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that your are throwing multiples exceptions with the exceptions group
see this post here.

[Throwing multiple exceptions in .Net/C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278466/throwing-multiple-exceptions-in-net-c)

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be writing to a logging framework. Writing it to response might pose a security risk. You can use log4Net / Logging application block or write your own simple logger which can be replaced later. But never ever send exception information to client.