# Multiple Exceptions have occurred, what's the right way to rethrow?

Tags: c#, exception

```
public void DoRiskyThings(List<Action> tasks)
{
  List<Exception> exceptions = new List<Exception>();
  foreach(Action task in tasks)
  {
    try {task()}
    catch (Exception e) {exceptions.Add(e)};
  }

  if (exceptions.Any())
  {
    //... what goes here?
  }
}
```

I'd like to preserve all the information (especially messages and stacktraces).

Comment: See this highly upvoted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/178464/555547

Comment: @Jason that's great but that method of rethrow only works from inside a catch block.  I'm outside of it.

Comment: @Jason: He wants to throw _multiple_ exceptions.  That won't work.

Comment: Just noticed that, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/278543/555547

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for the [`AggregateException` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aggregateexception.aspx).

Comment: Ah, I need .net 4, but I see I can make my own.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just bundle your list into a super-exception:

```
class MultiException : Exception
{
    public List<Exception> ExceptionsList { get; set; }
}
```