# Why does my for-each only throw one exception?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following code:

```
if (errorList != null && errorList.count() > 0)
{
    foreach (var error in errorList)
    {
        throw new Exception(error.PropertyName + " - " error.ErrorMessage, error.EntityValidationFailed);
    }    
}
```

Why does it only throw one exception when multiple errors are in the list?

Comment: Think about it this way - what do you *expect* the execution flow to be? What do you expect to happen when the first exception is thrown?

Comment: Exceptions halt normal execution.

More information, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/278466/throwing-multiple-exceptions-in-net-c

Comment: @pseudocoder: I'm asking the OP to think it through one step at a time, effectively.

Comment: @pseudocoder -- à la Socrates http://www.criticalthinking.org/pages/socratic-teaching/606

Comment: @roryap Interesting link, and after thinking about it i see that jon is asking a "probing" question by suggesting the issue occurs when the first exception is thrown.  Are we now going to a "Q&Q" format instead of "Q&A"? :P

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Becasue exception *breaks the code execution*, if it is not handled.

So the code like:

```
foreach (var error in errorList)
{
    try 
    {
          throw new Exception(error.PropertyName + " - " error.ErrorMessage, error.EntityValidationFailed);
    }

     catch(...) {}
}
```

will raise multiple exceptions, to be precise `errorList.Length` times, which will be handled by `catch(..)`, inside the loop body, *if not re-thrown* from the `catch(..)`, will remain there.

Answer (score 9):

You can only throw a single exception, you could however create a bunch of `Exceptions` and then throw an `AggregateException` at the end.

```
var exceptions = new List<Exception>();
foreach (var error in errorList)
{
    exceptions.Add(new Exception(error.PropertyName + " - " error.ErrorMessage, error.EntityValidationFailed));
}

if(exceptions.Any())
{
    throw new AggregateException(exceptions);
}
```

Comment: I'd name the variable `exceptions` though ;)

Comment: Oops, fat fingers ;-)